# merge array on basis on spefic key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 15
            [first_name] => Person1
            [surname] => Person1
            [totaltime] => 183.75
            [FirstValue] => 1
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [employee] => 15
        [first_name] => Person1
        [surname] => Person1
        [totaltime] => 183.75
        [SecondValue] => 2            
    )
)
```

I want output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 15
            [first_name] => Person1
            [surname] => Person1
            [totaltime] => 183.75
            [FirstValue] => 1
            [SecondValue] => 2
        )
)
```

I have a multi-dimensional array. Each element has an employee as key which can be the same or different. I want to merge the arrays with the same `EmployeeID`. Also 2 same employee may have different elements like `FirstValue`,`SecondValue`, etc.  I want to merge unique element as I've show in the above output.

Comment: What language is this? Arrays are everywhere... PHP Tag?

Comment: @bonCodigo ofcoz PHP

Comment: My question was for OP! or someone else who has been *dwelling upon* the editing for about 8 mins...yet no PHP tag.

Comment: Are you pulling this data from database and this is actually the result of your SQL query? If so, depends on what kind of driver you are using, look into FETCH ASSOCIATIVE array, that gets rid of your problem. And the other thing is, since keys values are duplicated, and this is multi dimensional array, you could just delete first dimension keys that are not odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = Array(
   Array
        (
            employee => 15,
            first_name => 'Person1',
           surname => 'Person1',
            totaltime => 183.75,
            FirstValue => 1
        ),
 Array
    (
        employee=> 15,
        first_name => Person1,
        surname=> Person1,
        totaltime => 183.75,
        SecondValue => 2            
    ),
       Array
        (
            employee => 16,
            first_name => 'Person1',
           surname => 'Person1',
            totaltime => 183.75,
            FirstValue => 1
        ));

$ids = array();                            // array employee => key

foreach($arr as $key => &$item)
   if(isset($ids[$item['employee']])) {    // is there such employee in ids
      $arr[$ids[$item['employee']]] =      // yes - add values from current item
          array_replace($arr[$ids[$item['employee']]], $item);  
      unset($arr[$key]);                   // and remove it from array
   }
   else $ids[$item['employee']] = $key;    // save current key

print_r($arr);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 15
            [first_name] => Person1
            [surname] => Person1
            [totaltime] => 183.75
            [FirstValue] => 1
            [SecondValue] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 16
            [first_name] => Person1
            [surname] => Person1
            [totaltime] => 183.75
            [FirstValue] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Check out [array_merge().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Dear its an single multidemisional array. and merging should be done on the basis of common specific  key.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$data = array(); // your data

array_merge($data[0],$data[1]); //merge it to first data
unset($data[1]); // and unset the second data with 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '<pre>';
```

Comment: Sir this array is dynamic not static.

Comment: @user375947 but the format always have $data[0] and $data[1] or can many datas there?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $employee) {
    if (isset($result[$employee['employee']])) {
        $result[$employee['employee']] += $employee;
    } else {
        $result[$employee['employee']] = $employee;
    }
}
```

Use the fact that array keys are unique (in `$result`) to deduplicate and merge the values.